# Emacs: Disable auto-fill minor mode when in idlwave major mode

Tags: emacs, emacs24

In Emacs how do I stop the `auto-fill` minor mode from loading when I start the `idlwave` major mode?

So far I have been completely unsuccessful at figuring out how to do this.  I have tried to use `remove-hook` for both `idl-mode-hook` and `text-mode-hook` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have enabled `auto-fill-mode` as a *global minor mode*, so it is on in all buffers by default. If that is the case, the task is not so much *not turning it on* in `idlwave-mode` but rather *turning it off*.

Most major modes provide a special hook variable: it's a list containing functions that are called whenever that major mode is invoked. For instance, with the following line you can make sure that `auto-fill-mode` will get turned off each time a buffer goes into `idlwave-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'idlwave-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-fill-mode 0)))
```

Put the above line in your init file (e.g. `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) and `auto-fill-mode` should be turned off in idlwave mode after you restarted Emacs.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for me once I removed the unnecessary argument in the lambda expressien.  I had previously tried to use: `(add-hook 'idlwave-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-fill-mode nil)))`, which was close but not quite right.

Comment: Yep, the lambda parameter was an oversight on my part. Glad it worked for you after all.